# How to make React load components after loading animation?

Tags: reactjs

I have a loading video(about 5s) that should be played before the application is loaded. How can I delay the loading time of the application when starting the app?

Answer (score 0):

There's quite a few ways to do this... providing some code could help determine the most optimal solution. It really depends on how you structure your application and what the requirements of your app is. Off the top of my head, if you don't care about SEO you can place a flag on the state of the root component or global store and then render it or your application depending on the status of the flag. If you care about SEO then the best solution is to have the video play in a fixed container with a higher z-index so it hides your app and then remove the container using javascript on a hook/lifecycle method on your main app component.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as the render method has been executed the componentDidMount function is called. The DOM can be accessed in this method, enabling to define DOM manipulations or data fetching operations. In your scenario you can add a setstate func in conmponentDidMount like this

```
componentDidMount(){
      this.setState({appLoaded: true})
       }
```

After that, You can load the video like this

```
<div>{
(this.state.appLoaded === true)?
 //Code goes here
 :'Loading...'
}</div>
```

You can use animation component instead of 'Loading...'.